# How to include local file of font awesome 4.1 without using CDN?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

[image: With font awesome effect]
This is the effect with font awesome, i only can get it when i using font awesome 4.1 CDN)

[image]
Using downloaded files, I included the fonts folder and font-awesome.css, but still no icon appear.

[image]
My link which is correct.

[image]
The font-awesome.css file path, i didn't change anything.

[image]
directory folders and files.

[image]
inside of font folder.

[image]
inside css folder.

********************************************************
I still didnt manage to get the icon show up, why??

Answer (score 38, accepted):

1. Download the fontawesome package from their website.
2. Extract the package where you will find the fontawesome.css file.
3. Copy this file to your css directory
4. copy all the fonts files from the extracted fontawesome package to your fonts folder.
5. Finally add the fontawesome.css to your html page by giving respective location of the css file.

AND Voila !

Comment: Now I got fonts folder with 5 files inside and i copy the whole folder, i also added font-awesome.css in css directory. I did all the steps that you told me, but, unfortunately, it still didn't work, what happen?

Comment: you should create a directory called fonts in your root first.after that you should add all the fontawesome's font files into that folder(only the font files not the .css files).Then copy the fontawesome.css into the directory where you place your .css files. after these steps try again.if still it doesn't work put fontawesome.css in the root and try again. this will work for sure =)

Comment: oh and you should correct the font path in your fontawesome.css too.in your case just remove the dots after src: url(...) (only the first couple of dots )..that should make it work

Comment: I got it working already. The problem is I typed in v3.1 style but I using v4.1, so it is not working.

Comment: The approach from this answer works like a charm after almost 4 years with changed folder structure naming('fonts'->'webfonts') and all.css was added. Thanks.

Answer (score 35):

Since I am using FontAwesome V5.3.1, I would like to update this answer since the folder structure was changed a bit in this version.

1. First, download the [FontAwesome v5.3.1](https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/fontawesome-free-5.3.1-web.zip) and extract the folder.
2. Copy the `all.min.css` file from the CSS folder and add it in your stylesheets.
3. Now, Copy the `webfonts` folder from FontAwesome extract and place it into your project one directory above to your `all.min.css` file. (Refer the image below)

[image]

Since `all.min.css` file refers to the `webfonts` folder now, we need to add this file along with the `webfonts` folder.

```
src: url("../webfonts/fa-brands-400.eot"); // This is how it is been referred now in all.min.css file.
```

Thank you.

Comment: This should be the correct answer, Thanks man, you saved my day.

Answer (score 14):

Just Downloading Css and linking to the file will not make sense,You should look into the css file....

You havent Downloaded the fonts folder in which all fonts styles are stored...
So Download it and give path to the font files located on your system ,
I have shown the links in boxes which you need to add links in font-awesome css files..

Download fonts from the cdn links and store in fonts folder..

[image: bootstram font awesome]

Hope this will work for you..

Answer (score 6):

You may find that the developer options in your favorite browser will give you an idea why the file is not working.

Font awesome requires the font files which come with it. The CSS file will reference these and try to include them, but currently won't be able to find them.

Download font-awesome-4.1.0.zip from [FontAwesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

Then extract this and put the css and fonts folders into your project. You can then reference the file as:

```
<link href="css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to network console, turn font filter ON
2. See which files are downloaded in background
3. Right click and open in new tab.. it will download that file
4. Put them in root DIR of your server storage

For eg. **htdocs/webfonts/fa-solid900.woff2**

5. Final download all.css file and link to your head section

Welcome in advance :)

[image]

Search for the required file using developer tools

[image]

Download file locally

[image]

Also download **all.css** or whatever cdn you are using

[image]

Putting downloaded font files in this **webfonts/** folder

Answer (score 1):

1. Download fontawesome (font-awesome-4.7.0) : http://fontawesome.io/get-started/
2. Unzip and copy into your project as-is.
3. In HTML reference font-awesome.min.css  e.g: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Answer (score 1):

this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEVbAsMrylU) is so helpful.
and work for me.

1. go to Font `Awesome.com` and download font awesome for the web.
2. extract this file.
3. put the webfonts file from the font awesome (download file) to your project file. (Delete the rest of the folder :) )
4. make new txt and copy the `all.css` file to it. (name it `font.css` and put it to the css folder).
5. add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fonts.css"`

Answer (score 1):

Download "font awesome" for Web from this link  https://fontawesome.com/download, extract the folder, and add a reference to the all.css file inside index.html
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is important to ensure relative links to eot & woff files other than css, in case you are using .htaccess

1) extract downloaded zip file to desired directory

in case .htaccess path is

H:\virtualhost\ .htaccess

and fontawesome css and fonts path is

H:\virtualhost\fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web\css

H:\virtualhost\fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web\webfonts

2) Make following entries in .htaccess

RewriteRule ^css/([^/]*).css$     /fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web/css/$1.css [L]

RewriteRule ^webfonts/([^/]*).eot$     /fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web/webfonts/$1.eot [L]

RewriteRule ^webfonts/([^/]*).woff2$     /fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web/webfonts/$1.woff2 [L]

RewriteRule ^webfonts/([^/]*).woff$     /fontawesome-free-5.4.2-web/webfonts/$1.woff [L]

3) Add following in head part of html

http://local-ip-address:port/css/all.css