# Attempting to include font-awesome without CDN

Tags: html, css

Before I being I just want to say I did research this question, and I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470752/how-to-include-local-file-of-font-awesome-4-1-without-using-cdn) post and followed the top answer's instruction but still nothing.

Okay here is a picture of my directory:

[image]

The fonts folder is just the regular fonts folder that comes with the font-awesome download. I then put the css file that came with font-awesome under css/font-awesome as shown below:

[image]

Here is a picture of my HTML code:

[image]

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Tinyone</title>

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link href="css/font-awesome/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery/JS/Fonts -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

I must be missing something, if anybody has any ideas could you please share them?

Thank you so much for reading, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check that directories are correct, and add `rel="stylesheet"` to Font-Awesome `<link>`

Comment: Wow, that was the issue! I forgot the rel="stylesheet" attribute. Thank you so much I was going insane.

Comment: @RompePC please provide your answer as a answer so this could be reproduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paths were all correct, but I forgot to include the `rel="stylesheet"` attribute to font-awesome `<link>`.

Thank you to RompePC for pointing this out to me.