# When I providing FontAwesome http link then icons are working but when host it locally its not working

Tags: html, css, frontend, font-awesome, web-frontend

When I provide cnd link:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Then its showing icons and working fine.

Here is code [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/mdL3kuhw/6/)

When I copy and host the same css file locally then its not working
Here is example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/mdL3kuhw/5/) code

Why its not working when I host locally? Is there any restrictions or license problem?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the path where you placed in tomcat. If you copied the file, then you should add a relative path in `<link>` tag.

Comment: @ShashankGb I added my question and provided more information

Comment: try this `<link href='assets/lib/fontawesome/all.min.css'>`

Comment: @ShashankGb when I click in html view source then its showing all.min.css but still not showing icons

Comment: If the above path doesn't work can you provide a path of `index.html` file or the html file where you included `font awesome icon`

Comment: Can you provide a minimal code of icon and it's result preview?

Comment: `<a href="#" class="toggle_hide_password"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash" aria-hidden="true"></i> </a>`

Comment: @ShashankGb the problem is not with code because everything working fine when I provide CDN link. Its really strange why the copied css file is not working

Comment: Are you getting square box in place of icon? or empty?

Comment: I am getting empty

Comment: I think you should follow the steps present here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470752/how-to-include-local-file-of-font-awesome-4-1-without-using-cdn

Comment: @ShashankGb can you see my updated question? I added jsfiddle code

Comment: I tested your code... It's working fine for me

Comment: @ShashankGb yes I said that earlier but the problem starts when I copy paste the same CDN CSS to my local machine then its not work like I provided this link `http://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/mdL3kuhw/5/`. I am trying to understand why its working online but not when I host on my own server?

Comment: @ShashankGb have you please tested this link http://jsfiddle.net/Raakh5/mdL3kuhw/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix I found is to save this css file locally and edit it. `<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Find `url` and replace `../` to `../../` because my web font folder location was `assets/webfonts` not root

Comment: Thats why I asked you `indexhtml` file path but you didn't provide. Its okay, you find your solution.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using a CDN network instead of Font Awesome's kit code. If that's the case, I'd recommend you using the Kit code of your kit. That'll help you in showing icon on your site, locally or hosted doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by your reply or can you refer any URL or Video that can explain what you said?

Comment: I am just asking you to, got to Font Awesome and go to Your Kits section from the left nav. And then copy your kit code(A Script) and then use it directly from FA and not from any CDN Network.
Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiw68Y-hPlA for reference.

Comment: I did what you said but showing empty boxes. When I add cdn link then its working fine

Comment: please see my provided links of jsfiddle in my updated question

Comment: I cannot see the Kit Code or the Script of FA Library. It looks like:
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c1bcb46dc6.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
Include your script tag in the head of your HTML.
Log into your FA Account, go to Kits section from the right navigation and then copy the kit script(if any) or create one.
I hope this solves your problem.