# Can I load fontawesome from a file:// location?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I have a html report that runs as a file on a local disk like `c:\app\report.html`. It is not being served from a web server.

The machine that shows the report is not and will not be connected to internet.

When I reference fontawesome like below, all icons show, with no problem:

`<link1 href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

However, when I download `all.min.css` to my local directory and reference it like blow all fonts show as square box:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/fontawesome/all.min.css" />`

It seems that I can't load fontawesome from local disk.

Is there any way I can load and use fontawesome from local disk?

Comment: I think this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470752/how-to-include-local-file-of-font-awesome-4-1-without-using-cdn

Comment: It is generally not possible to use Font Awesome from a file:// location, as the font files are loaded from a remote server and require a web server to work properly.